# Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException with an Empty Message

Tags: .net, oracle, odac

been fighting this for a few days now and getting a little frustrated...
I am working on a web service that consumes an oracle store procedure which returns a custom type object.
To do so I have been working with Oracle ODT (unmanaged).
Since I have a64 bit machine and a matching Oracle Client (mimicking our server environment) I complied the solution to 32 bit, added all relevant dlls (oci, etc...) as well as oracle data access- all 32 bit version.
Running it via visual Studio all works perfectly.
However on deployment to the IIS (making sure that the application pool supports 32bit) I cant seem to open the connection to the database- I am getting Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException with an Empty Message. If I understand correctly this may indicate that the ODAC is not able to load all dlls (all placed in the same folder). I can’t figure out what’s the difference here between the IIS and the Visual Studio in terms of running the ODAC.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Check your exception handling. Usually there should be an error message unless you code something like `catch {}`.

Comment: Is the Oracle Client also 32 bit?

Comment: have you considered using the managed driver?

Comment: My Oracle Client is 64 bit which is why I’m attaching all dlls - to make the app use the instant client attached instead of the installed client ( the 32/64 thing is a company mess...)

Comment: Unfortunately the managed client doesn’t support UDTs so I cannot use it

Comment: I am actually catching the exception- it’s just that there is no message in it...